# Regex always returning either always true or always false regardless of valid test value

Tags: javascript, html, regex, wordpress

I am trying to validate a form field using Regex. The field should contain 5 numbers (ie 12345 = valid, 1234a = invalid, 123456 = invalid), that is it. no more, no less. The problem is with different regex formats, the .test() method either always returns true, or always returns false. It never works for correct values and fails for incorrect values. All regex testers test the regex successfully for JavaScript but when I add it to my page (WordPress), I get these issues. I read up about the /g field should be removed and tried all that. still no luck.

HTML:

```
<form name="newform" action="Create.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST" >
    Code <br/><br/><input id="code" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="code"  onkeypress="CodeStyleRefresh()" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm(){
    var CodePattern = new RegExp(/\b\d{5}\b/);

    if(CodePattern.test(document.forms["newform"]["code"].value) == true)
    {
        return true;
}
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
function CodeStyleRefresh(){
    document.getElementById("code").setAttribute("style", "background-color: #ffffff;");
}
</script>
```

Some other ways I have tried to specify the expression:

```
var CodePattern = new RegExp(/\b\d{5}\b/);
var CodePattern = new RegExp('/\b\d{5}\b/');
var CodePattern = /\b\d{5}\b/;
var CodePattern = '/\b\d{5}\b/';
var CodePattern = \b\d{5}\b;
var CodePattern = '\b\d{5}\b';
```

This is my first time ever touching regex and I am fairly new to the JavaScript family as well. Not having such a good time.

**UPDATE:**

I have gone back to basics. My JavaScript now looks as follows based on a few suggestions:

```
function validateForm(event)
{   
    console.log("Im running the script!");
    console.log(event.target.querySelector("[name=code]").value);

    var CodePattern = new RegExp(/\b\d{5}\b/);
    var codeVal = event.target.querySelector("[name=code]").value;

    if(CodePattern.test(codeVal) == true)
    {
        alert("Expression Passed!");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Expression Failed!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

My HTML is now:

```
<form name="newform" onsubmit="return validateForm(event)" method="POST">
  Code
  <input id="code" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="code" />
  <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

Still this expression is only hitting the failed state and alerts expression failed.

If it helps, I am adding the JavaScript to a WordPress page, the form is normal html on the same page. I have tried adding the JavaScript to both the header and the footer but this does not change anything. I'm starting to think I should just check if the length of the field = 5 and if I can then cast it to an int instead of using RegEx at all!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Returns false always for both valid and invalid values

Comment: @anubhava, Returns false always for both valid and invalid values. I need the if statement as I need to change some styles if not true. ie make the textbox red.

Comment: @anubhava Returns the exact value that I entered into the input box. 1234 logs 1234 and 12345 logs 12345. yet both validations fail where 12345 should have passed. My script is in the footer. although I cannot see that this will make a difference as I can see the code is executing, its just the result that is wrong.

Comment: ok in that case `var CodePattern = /\b\d{5}\b/;` should work

Comment: @anubhava still false. maybe I should look for a different method of comparison other than regex.text();

Comment: Add an `alert` statement before `return true` and see if that prints

Comment: @anubhava. Please see the update in the question. I have added alert and still false is returned. The only alert returned is "Expression Failed!"

Comment: Check my answer below. There is a live demo in that answer and clicking on **`Create`** button prints `Expression Passed!`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is fine. If you are only getting the error when you upload your code to your wordpress site, I'd be tempted to say that your problem is your context, perhaps you have more than one form with the same name?

Try a context aware piece of code, update your html to:

```
<form name="newform" onsubmit="return validateForm(event)" method="POST">
  Code
  <input id="code" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="code" onkeypress="CodeStyleRefresh()" />
  <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

And your javascript:

```
function validateForm(event){
    var myRegex = new RegExp(/\b\d{5}\b/);
    //event.target holds the node element that triggered the function in our case, the Form itself
    var myValue = event.target.querySelector("[name=code]").value; //here we find the input with the name=code inside the form that triggered the event

  return myRegex.test(myValue) //return true if it passed, false if not
}
```

Comment: I will certainly give this a go. Thanks. I only have one form on the page so it cant be a duplicate name issue.

Comment: It should work correctly, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5gwdzbw/1/)  where I used your exact same validation, and it's working well, also you have a syntax error in your html in `action=Create.php"` you are missing the opening double quote ("), I doubt that's the problem but it's best if you fixed that

Comment: I have tried the solution you suggested but still it returns false for both valid and invalid values. I have updated the question with what I have done. I have stripped the JavaScript down to the bare minimum. Still no luck. PS, the action=Create.php error was a typo in the question.

Comment: add `return true;` in the if statement `if(CodePattern.test(codeVal) == true)
    {
        alert("Expression Passed!");
    }`

Comment: The problem is that CodePattern.test(codeVal) always returns false. Even when logging it to console, it returns false for invalid AND invalid expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot insert this much code in comments, I am posting an answer here to show how it all works.

```js
function validateForm(frm, evt)
{   
    var codeVal = frm.code.value;

    var CodePattern = /\b\d{5}\b/;

    // comment below line after testing
    evt.preventDefault();
    
    if(CodePattern.test(codeVal) == true)
    {
        console.log("Expression Passed!");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Expression Failed!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="newform" onsubmit="return validateForm(this, event)" method="POST">
    Code <br/><br/>
    <input id="code" type="text" value="abc 12345 foo bar" name="code" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, its still doing the same. It works in plain HTML and when running the code here on SO but as soon as I add it to wordpress, it always returns false. This is so frustrating. I think I should just look at a different solution for validation other than Regex. My write some code the longwinded way.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the suggestions. I have learnt a few things by looking at them all and I have made a few changes.

I could not however get the regex to work properly in wordpress. I was forced to create a longwinded, dirtier solution to this. I will continue to look at possible solutions and test on other wordpress sites, but for now, this is the code I am using to validate the field:

```js
  function validateForm(frm, evt)
  { 
   var codeVal = frm.code.value;
   console.log("Code Value: " + String(codeVal));
   // comment below line after testing
   evt.preventDefault();
   
   var lenPass = false;
   var strlen = codeVal.length;
   
   if(strlen == 5)
   {
    lenPass = true;
   }
   
   if(lenPass)
   {
    var c1 = Number.isNaN(Number(codeVal.charAt(0)));
    var c2 = Number.isNaN(Number(codeVal.charAt(1)));
    var c3 = Number.isNaN(Number(codeVal.charAt(2)));
    var c4 = Number.isNaN(Number(codeVal.charAt(3)));
    var c5 = Number.isNaN(Number(codeVal.charAt(4)));
    
    console.log(c1);
    console.log(c2);
    console.log(c3);
    console.log(c4);
    console.log(c5);
    
    var pass = true;
    
    if(c1)
    {
     pass = false;
    }  
    if(c2)
    {
     pass = false;
    }
    if(c3)
    {
     pass = false;
    }
    if(c4)
    {
     pass = false;
    }
    if(c5)
    {
     pass = false;
    }
    
    if(pass)
    {
     alert("Expression Stage 2 Passed!");
     return true;
    }
    else
    {
     alert("Expression Stage 2 Failed!");
     return false;
    }
   }
   else
   {
    alert("Expression Stage 1 Failed!");
    return false;
   }
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="newform" onsubmit="return validateForm(this, event)" method="POST">
  Code <br/><br/>
  <input id="code" type="text" value="" name="code" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Create" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```